# Problems with session ids on parallel threads

Tags: python, session, python-multiprocessing, pool

So I am trying to use **`multiprocessing`** to iterate concurrently through files in separate folders. I have a function that calls the parallel process:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

lsFolders = ['Folder1', 'Folder2']

pool = Pool( processes = 6 )

iterateThroughFiles = IterateThroughFiles() # instantiated by call to pool.map()

pool.map( iterateThroughFiles.runProcess, lsFolders )
```

Then I have the implementation of the **`IterateThroughFiles`**-class:

```
class IterateThroughFiles( object ):

  def runProcess( self, folder ):
      self.sessionId = uuid.uuid4()
      print( self.sessionId )             # Prints a correct sessionId
      logAtLevel( "INFO", "Session ID of: "
                         + str( self.sessionId )
                         + " has been generated for folder: "
                         + folder
                           )

      print( self.sessionId )             # Prints only the second generated
      #                                   # session id for both threads
      print( folder )                     # Prints the correct folder
```

When I generate the **`sessionId`** and print it directly after, the `sessionId` is correct, additionally the **`logAtLevel()`** wrapper function logs the correct value of the `sessionId`.

The next print statement, though, prints only the second session id and apparently the first `sessionId` is forgotten in the thread.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I thought when running in parallel each thread was distinct in terms of the objects it created and its memory? Is this incorrect? Does this have something to with the uuid generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that  you are only generating one instance of `IterateThroughFiles` which is being used in both threads.
Instead, you want something like the following

```
def factory(folder):
    return IterateThroughFiles().runProcess(folder)
```

and pass that factory function into map.
That way you will get two instances.

Answer (score 1):

> `pool.map(iterateThroughFiles.runProcess, lsFolders)`

In this line you are calling `runProcess` many times on a single instance of the class IterateThroughFiles. If you are thinking of each instance as a session, you need to instantiate a new object for each folder in lsFolders.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

lsFolders = ['Folder1', 'Folder2']

pool = Pool(processes=6)

def worker(folder):
    p = IterateThroughFiles()
    p.runProcess(folder)

pool.map(worker, lsFolders)
```

This way, the worker function creates a NEW instance of `IterateThroughFiles` for each folder, and that way in the `runProcess` function, `self` refers to that individual instance, rather than re-using the same instance for each folder.